# is editing images violating copyrights

Tags: copyright, intellectual-property

Lets say I want to build iOS quiz with guessing images, and want to guess pokemons. If I edit image like :
[image]

is it violating copyrights?

Comment: Yes, it is. The Pokémon is still very recognizable.

Comment: Also, it's a [derivative work](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative_work) of an existing work.

Comment: Yes. It is. This was a massive problem back in the days of RPG Maker VX forums, too. One person would sprite a tileset and someone else would have the audacity to recolor it and claim ownership.